# How to remove pin from Subaru ECU plug

Tags: electrical, subaru, electronic-control-module

I need to add a cable into an existing plug for a 2007 Subaru Legacy (BP) vehicle.

For practice I picked up an identical plug from the wreckers.  Figured I could use the pin and cable from the test plug on the real project.

These things are small (plug body 24mm W x 16mm H ) although each connection has a hole right above (or below?) it.

You might see from the photos I've tried using a small screwdriver and needlework pin to release the cable with no luck.  Any tips appreciated.

UPDATE: The holes for the extraction tool seem to be below each connector and when removed the crimped side of the cable entry points downwards.  Tried various implements to extract the pins but did not purchase a specific tool. 
 Only the hacksaw approach worked for me.

[image: Rear of connector, showing cable entry]
[image: Front of connector showing sockets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experience of other plugs, you need to make a small implement that will slide into the little rectangular slot next to the connector square hole with the wire that you want to remove - the idea is to press down the locking "tooth" that is holding it in.

Luckily you have some spare ones to practise on !

If you can't get that to work, then just hacksaw the plug open and rescue the pin you want...

Answer (score 4):

At the end of each wire is a terminal. In order for the terminal to stay in place while the male pin of the opposing connector is pressed in, there is a small locking tab on the terminal (arrow).

[image]

Using a removal tool, or a small stiff pin device, you can place it in the slot next to the terminal you wish to remove. Press in so the tool overcomes the locking tab. As you do so, pull the wire lightly from the back.

[image]

Some of these can be rather stiff. Also, I have found that pushing the terminal inward while attempting to press the lock down helps. They make special tools for this, but they can be expensive if you are only going to use them once.

Comment: I depinned an entire Impreza ECU harness a while back. I used a quilting needle as the implement of torture. I ran a ribbon through the back end so it was easy to locate and hold on to during use. On the Subaru plugs, they usually have a small notch on the side you insert the pin into. Once you figure out the first one, it becomes pretty easy. Good call on pushing the terminal in when disconnecting as this makes getting it out a lot easier.